# How to pick only certain data

Tags: r, subset

I would like to pick up only data in column **x** and **x-date** for each **person**.
(in condition of **x-date** is between ***day1*** and ***day2*** columns for each **person**). Please see the picture below

For example,

```
a, x=111, x-date=2/2/2016
b, x=8990, x-dates=2/3/2016
c, x=333, x-dates=5/5/2011
```

[image: image of data.frame]

Comment: My first suggestion would be to paste your data using `dput(df)` instead of using an image, see -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: What have you done so far? And +1 on `dput(df)`; the structure of your data (e.g. the format of your dates) is relevant here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your question right, and if all your dates are in Date format, you could probably just do something like that :

Base R :

```
 df[(df$x-date > df$day1 & df$x-date < df$day2), c('person', 'x', 'x-date')]
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the subset function.

```
subset(df, x==111 & x-date=='2/2/2016', select = c(person,x,x-date))
```